# setting up nginx to reverse proxy heroku site

Tags: nginx, heroku

I have two application hosted on heroku. First one is based in `Go` and second on `reactjs` and `nodejs` with `nginx`.

I use `nginx` to proxy `node_react.herokuapp.com` application request to `gosite.herokuapp.com`. And the problem is i am not able to communicate with gosite through nginx.

My `nginx.conf.erb` file looks like this.

```
daemon off;

worker_processes <%= ENV['NGINX_WORKERS'] || 4 %>;

events {
    use epoll;
    accept_mutex on;
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {

    server {
        listen <%= ENV["PORT"] %>;
        server_name _;

        access_log  access.log;
        error_log   error.log;


        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8080;
            proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

        location /api {
            proxy_pass         http://gosite.herokuapp.com;
            proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }



        location ~ .*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|txt|js|css|svg|woff|apk|jar|zip)$
        {
            proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8080;
            proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

        location ~ .*(__webpack_hmr)$
        {
            proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8080;
            proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
    }
}
```

I can see nothing in network preview of browser.

I had the similar problem while nodejs was making api call without nginx proxy but i fixed that by setting host header as `request(url,{header:{'host':'gosite.herokuapp.com'}})` Now i am having problem with nginx.